# CS6 Fluid Grids 3 types of background 100% wide?

Tags: dreamweaver, fluid-layout

I'm new to fluid grids, btw i'v started learning about diferent types and now trying to build page in cs6 (maybe not the right choice). I have a problem which I didn't have when building pages that are not fluid. I need to create different background images for header and footer that are 100% width and as wide as the screen, not just as wide as media-query, and also to setup the page to be 960 centered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the header wider than the rest of the page?
To do so, create different div's in the document. For example, I normally work all of my divs inside a master div, so that my entire page is affected. For example, a page with a main div, header, body, and footer: 
`#main` `#header` `#body` `#footer`. The header, body, and footer are all create inside of the main div. To make everything float in the center of the page at a width of 960px, then you'd simply apply the attribute to the `#main` div like so:

```
#main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The margin will cause the div to float in the center. It does not have to be any specific value, but you do need a margin to the left and right of the page.

To only float the remainder of the page, create everything else inside of the main div but the header and footer, and set the width of the header to 100%. So you would have the following overall snippet:

```
#header, #footer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you don't already do so, it'd be wise to add some padding on either side so that the images and text don't appear to run into the side of the page (which makes it difficult to read or view). 5px is usually all I add.